# Updating dash datatable using callback function

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dash dashboard I built. I would like to add more interactivity. I want to allow users to select an option on a drop down menu and the data shown in my datatable is filtered according to said selection

This is how I have defined my datatable

```
html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='punchstats',
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in punch_stats.columns],
        data = punch_stats.to_dict('records'),
        page_current=0,
        page_size=2,
        page_action='custom',
        sort_action='custom',
        sort_mode='multi',
        style_table={'overflowX':'scroll',
                     'maxHeight':'300px'},
        style_header={'backgroundColor':'rgb(30, 30, 30)'},
        style_cell={'backgroundColor':'rgb(50,50,50)',
                    'color':'white'},
        sort_by=[]),
])
```

These are the drop down filters I have defined

```
dcc.Dropdown(
    id='weight_class',
    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in data['division'].unique()],
    multi=True
),
dcc.Dropdown(
    id='gender',
    options=[{'label': i, 'value':i} for i in fight_outcomes['sex'].unique()],
    multi=True
),
```

and this is the function that should update my table according to the dropdown selections

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('punchstats','data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('punchstats','page_current'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('punchstats','page_size'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('punchstats','sort_by'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('weight_class','value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('gender','value')])
def update_punchstats(page_current,page_size,sort_by,weight_class,gender):
    if weight_class is None or weight_class == []:
        weight_class == WEIGHT_CLASS
    if gender is None or gender == []:
        gender == GENDER
    punchstatsdf = [(punch_stats['division'].isin(weight_class))]
    punchstatsdf = [(punchstatsdf['sex'].isin(gender))]
    print(sort_by)
    if len(sort_by):
        sorted_df = punchstatsdf.sort_values(
            [cols['column_id'] for cols in sort_by],
            ascending=[
                cols['direction'] == 'asc'
                for col in sort_by
            ],
            inplace=False
        )
    else:
        sorted_df = punchstatsdf
    return sorted_df.iloc[page_current*page_size:(page_current+ 1)*page_size].to_dict('records')
```

Not sure how to add a minimum reproducible example for this type of question, hoping there is something wrong with the function logic that can be spotted by someone who has more experience with this package.

Just to reiterate the problem. When I select a given weight class and/or gender the datatable does not filter data that specifically in the selected weight class/gender

**UPDATE**

Through research I found out that in order to allow users to sort by column I had to change sort_action to native as custom implied that I had to specify the sort action myself. However I am still struggling to allow users to filter the data that appears in the data table based on the dropdown selection.

Here is my updated code. I have also added:

```
html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='punchstats',
            columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in sorted(punch_stats.columns)],
            # data = punch_stats.to_dict('records'),
            page_current=0,
            page_size=5,
            page_action='native',
            sort_action='native',
            column_selectable="single",
            row_selectable="single",
            sort_mode='multi',
            style_table={'overflowX':'scroll',
                         'maxHeight':'300px'},
            style_header={'backgroundColor':'rgb(30, 30, 30)'},
            style_cell={'backgroundColor':'rgb(50,50,50)',
                        'color':'white'},
            sort_by=[]),
    ])
```

and:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('punchstats','data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('weight_class','value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('gender','value')])
def update_punchstats(weight_class,gender):
    if weight_class is None or weight_class == []:
        weight_class == WEIGHT_CLASS
    if gender is None or gender == []:
        gender == GENDER
    punchstatsdf = [(punch_stats['division'].isin(weight_class))]
    punchstatsdf = [(punchstatsdf['sex'].isin(gender))]
    return [
        punchstatsdf.to_dict('records')
    ]
```

I have also tried updating my dash datatable in my callback function by returning a dictionary:

```
def update_punchstats(weight_class,gender):
    if weight_class is None or weight_class == []:
        weight_class == WEIGHT_CLASS
    if gender is None or gender == []:
        gender == GENDER
    punchstats = [(punch_stats['division'].isin(weight_class))]
    punchstats = [(punchstats['sex'].isin(gender))]
    return {
        'data': punchstats.to_dict("records")
    }
```

However, this returns an empty datatable

Here is the data I am using:

```
path_five = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EmmS21/SpringboardCapstoneBoxingPredictionWebApp/master/boxingdata/punchingstats.csv'
punch_stats = pd.read_csv(path_five)
```

Comment: Where does the callback function get the dataframe from? If you want to update it, that should be another `Input` or `State` used in the callback. What's going wrong currently?

Comment: @coralvanda gender and weight class are currently inputs in my callback, but selecting a particular gender or weight division does not update my datatable

Comment: I don't have your data to test with, but this looks wrong: `punchstatsdf = [(punchstatsdf['sex'].isin(gender))]`. I believe the syntax should be like this `df = df[df['sex'].isin(gender)]`

Comment: @coralvanda the syntax isn't the issue.

Comment: @coralvanda I have also added the data I am using

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Here's what I did.

First, I changed these lines:

```py
punchstats = [(punch_stats['division'].isin(weight_class))]
punchstats = [(punchstats['sex'].isin(gender))]
```

to this:

```py
punchstatsdf = punch_stats[punch_stats['division'].isin(weight_class)]
punchstatsdf = punchstatsdf[punchstatsdf['sex'].isin(gender)]
```

You also have problems with your variable assignment. I don't know what `GENDER` and `WEIGHT_CLASS` are, but I assume they're lists of strings. You need to assign using a single `=` and not the double `==`. I had to do that as well.

Last of all, I simply did `return punchstatsdf.to_dict('records')`. You do not need to put it inside a list or a dict.